# Calculating list cumulative sum in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Write a function that returns the running sum of list. e.g. running [1,2,3,5] is [1,3,6,11]. I write this function below which just can return the final sum of all the values among the list.So how can i separate them one by one?

```
sumlist' xx=aux xx 0
    where aux [] a=a
          aux (x:xs) a=aux xs (a+x)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can adjust your function to produce a list by simply prepending `a+x` to the result on each step and using the empty list as the base case:

```
sumlist' xx = aux xx 0
    where aux [] a = []
          aux (x:xs) a = (a+x) : aux xs (a+x)
```

However it is more idiomatic Haskell to express this kind of thing as a fold or scan.

Comment: ``aux (x:xs) a = a `seq` (a+x) : aux xs (a+x)``, to make it less dependent on strictness analyzer.

Answer (score 40):

I think you want a combination of [`scanl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:scanl1) and `(+)`, so something like

```
scanl1 (+) *your list here*
```

scanl1 will apply the given function across a list, and report each intermediate value into the returned list.

Like, to write it out in pseudo code,

```
scanl1 (+) [1,2,3]
```

would output a list like:

```
[a, b, c] where { a = 1, b = a+2, c = b+3 }
```

or in other words,

```
[1, 3, 6]
```

[Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#folds) has a lot of great examples and descriptions of scans, folds, and much more of Haskell's goodies.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

While scanl1 is clearly the "canonical" solution, it is still instructive to see how you could do it with foldl:

```
sumList xs = tail.reverse $ foldl acc [0] xs where 
  acc (y:ys) x = (x+y):y:ys
```

Or pointfree:

```
sumList = tail.reverse.foldl acc [0] where 
  acc (y:ys) x = (x+y):y:ys
```

Here is an ugly brute force approach:

```
sumList xs = reverse $ acc $ reverse xs where
  acc [] = []
  acc (x:xs) = (x + sum xs) : acc xs
```

There is a cute (but not very performant) solution using `inits`:

```
sumList xs = tail $ map sum $ inits xs
```

Again pointfree:

```
sumList = tail.map sum.inits
```

Comment: @sepp2k: How do you get the sum of the elements coming left if you start at the right side of the list?

Comment: @Lamdei: Sorry, I wasn't thinking right. However not being lazy is still a good reason not to use foldl (or your brute force approach).

Comment: Why `reverse`?  `sumList = (\`snd\` []) . foldl (\\(a, k) x -> (a+x, k . (a+x:))) (0, id)` works just fine in the forward direction.

Comment: @ephemient: That's cool, I didn't think of that, but probably too complicated for a beginner.

Comment: @ephemient your snippet reimplements `scanl1 (+)`, except it will force the whole spine of the input list before returning so won't work on infinite lists. (yeah, 10 years have passed... :))

Answer (score 1):

Related to another question I found this way:

```
rsum xs = map (\(a,b)->a+b) (zip (0:(rsum xs)) xs)
```

I think it is even quite efficient.

Comment: `map (uncurry f) $ zip xs ys == zipWith f xs ys`, so this function is `rsum xs = zipWith (+) (0:(rsum xs)) xs`, but it isn't reusing the results as it should (so is quadratic), like the following would (so is linear): `rsum xs = rs where rs = zipWith (+) (0:rs) xs`, or `scanl1 (+) xs`, too (is linear).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how canonical is this but it looks beautiful to me :)

```
sumlist' [] = []
sumlist' (x:xs) = x : [x + y | y <- sumlist' xs]
```

Comment: this is quadratic. [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732282/calculating-list-cumulative-sum-in-haskell/68262811#comment120648331_39925903).

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, it would be nice to find a solution that is both linear and non-strict. The problem is that the right folds and scans do not allow you to look at items to the left of you, and the left folds and scans are all strict on the input list. One way to achieve this is to define our own function which folds from the right but looks to the left. For example:

```
sumList:: Num a => [a] -> [a]
sumList xs = foldlr (\x l r -> (x + l):r) 0 [] xs
```

It's not too difficult to define foldr so that it is non-strict in the list. Note that it has to have two initialisers -- one going from the left (0) and one terminating from the right ([]):

```
foldlr :: (a -> b -> [b] -> [b]) -> b -> [b] -> [a] -> [b]
foldlr f l r xs =
    let result = foldr (\(l', x) r' -> f x l' r') r (zip (l:result) xs) in
        result
```

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: Thank you Drazisil and Yunnosch. I have edited my answer to remove the questions and make it more clearly an answer to the original question.