# About scanl1 in Haskell

Tags: haskell

A function should return the running sums of a list. Such as calling it with `[1,2,3,5]` returns `[1,3,6,11]`.

I wrote this function like below:

```
sumlist' :: [xx]=[xx]
sumlist' []=[]
sumlist' [x]=x
sumlist' xx=scanl1 (+) [xx]
```

When I run it in GHcI, it shows me that I do multiple declarations. So what's wrong with this function?

Comment: Please use the code sample tags to make your Haskell code more readable

Comment: @Zach L: The poster [did that](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2c4cc0fb-9ac7-4112-b119-3911f779f113/view-source), but it didn't work because there weren't newlines before and after the code sample as well.  It's fixed now.

Comment: All you need is the last line. The other two are redundant (actually the second is a type error).

Comment: @Joey Adams: Ah, my apologies :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732282/problem-in-haskell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you want to change the declaration to something like

```
sumlist' :: [xx]->[xx]
```

since sumlist' takes a List of type xx and returns a List of type xx.

Since we're using (+) in the call to scanl1, and (+) needs types of `Num`, we're going to need to scoot back to the definition of sumlist' and tell it that we specifically take lists of Nums.

```
sumlist' :: Num xx=>[xx]->[xx]
```

scanl1 can deal with empty lists, so all you need is

```
sumlist' :: Num xx=>[xx]->[xx]
sumlist' xx = scanl1 (+) xx
```

However, if you still, just for kicks, want to try your code, you'll need to fix the last two lines:

For the case where x contains **1** element, you have:

```
sumlist' [x] = x
```

Remember, sumlist' takes a list and **returns a list**, so just return the list back!

```
sumlist' [x] = [x]
```

And for the last case, where you take a list called xx, you have

```
sumlist' xx=scanl1 (+) [xx]
```

xx is already a list, so GHC will think `[xx]` is a **list of lists**, so just remove the brackets

```
sumlist' xx=scanl1 (+) xx
```

So our revised code is something like:

```
sumlist' :: Num xx=>[xx]->[xx]
sumlist' []=[]
sumlist' [x]=[x]
sumlist' xx=scanl1 (+) xx
```

As [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient) said, if you need to input multiple lines to GHCi, use the :load command.

Hope this helps, and happy hacking :-)

Comment: Nitpicking: YOu can use `:{` and `:}` as well. Since GHC 7.0 it even supports layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
sumlist' :: [xx]=[xx]
```

That line is wrong.  The part after the `::` should be a type declaration, which looks like `[a] -> [a]`.  (Yes, it looks *like* the pattern/value `[xx]`, but isn't.)

Don't try entering multi-line declarations into GHCi, it treats each input line separately.  Just save it in a file and `:load` the file from GHCi.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but a better way to define sumList using higher order functions would be:

```
sumList :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
sumList = tail . scanl (+) 0
```

Note also that your type signature, despite the obvious mistaken `=` for `->`, would have been "too polymorphic" in that your function only works on lists of "some type in the `Num` class", not "a list of any type".