# How to use 'aux' keyword in Haskell

Tags: haskell, scope

Okay, I've looked on about 4-5 websites that offered to teach Haskell and not one of them explained the keyword `aux`. They just started using it. I've only really studied Java and C (never saw it in either if it exists), and I've never really encountered it before this class that I'm taking on Haskell. All I can really tell is that it provides the utility to create and store a value within a function. So what exactly does it do and how is it properly used and formatted? In particular, could you explain its use while recursing? I don't think that its use is any different, but just to make sure I thought I would ask.

Comment: You mean `aux` as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732282/problem-in-haskell)? If so, it is not a keyword, just an auxiliary function defined in local scope.

Comment: Yes, that's the aux I was referring to! I've seen it quite a bit in tutorials, but it's never brought up as a separate topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no keyword `aux`, my guess is this is just the name they used for a local function.

Just like you can define top-level values:

```
myValue = 4
```

or top-level functions:

```
myFunction x = 2 * x
```

you can similarly define local values:

```
myValue =
    let myLocalValue = 3 in
    myLocalValue + 1

-- or equivalently:
myValue = myLocalValue + 1
    where myLocalValue = 3
```

or a local function:

```
myValue =
    let myLocalFunction x = 2 * x in
    myLocalFunction 2

-- or equivalently:
myValue = myLocalFunction 2
    where myLocalFunction x = 2 * x
```

Your teacher simply named the local function `aux` instead of `myLocalFunction`.

Comment: To add to this answer: When you use an auxiliary function like that to improve performance while recursing, it is a common idiom to call the function "`go`". Other than that, I've actually never heard of anyone naming it `aux`. Keep in mind that if there is a sensible name for the function, you should probably use that instead of something like `aux` that doesn't tell you very much about what the function does!

Comment: `rec` [is an actual keyword](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#rec) though :)

Comment: @duplode I'm yet to find this extension being useful.

Comment: @swish Yup, the use cases are quite specific. I only know it because I happened to stumble upon one of them recently.

Comment: @kqr I like using just `g` (and `f`, `h`, in case there are several). Even less semantic and visual noise.

Comment: @kqr I know some people call it `aux` in OCaml, never seen it in Haskell though.

Comment: @swish. `reflex`, `reflex-dom`. Position of a term in a monad controls where it is render in a web page, `rec` allows values from lower elements to be used higher in the page. Essential for those libraries.